# Best way to show elapsed time used and available of a resource

Tags: datetime, availability

I have a resource - in this case a golf cart.  i want to show the reserved vs. available time for each cart (limited number of carts vs golfers).  so i have the Date, End Reserve datetime, Start Reserve datetime, Cart Number, Customer Name
2017-12-27  2017-12-27 07:30:00.000 2017-12-27 12:00:00.000 GC20    KHEMPRAPA, CHAMLONG

and what to show on a daily basis the reserved vs available times for each cart.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mln.png)

Comment: This is for PowerBi

Comment: disregard... figured it out with "As Timeline" custom visual if anyone else is looking to do the same.